# Count from inner select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I am trying to execute the following query in SQL server but I am getting error. Can somebody explain me how to count the inner select statement?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from

(Select ID,
      COUNT(ID)
  FROM [Testing].[dbo].[Bench] group by ID  having COUNT(*) =5);
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: If you are counting all columns found per row then you should keep the *. Otherwise you should use a specific column name when counting rows found. Just a pointer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose you just missed the name of the second column:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    Select id, COUNT(id) count_of_id
    FROM [Testing].[dbo].[Bench]
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(*) =5
);
```

Comment: SQL Server requires an alias on the subquery.

Answer (score 7):

Try below code :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from

(Select ID,
      COUNT(ID) as cnt
  FROM [Testing].[dbo].[Bench] group by ID  having COUNT(*) =5) tbl;
```

Comment: I was missing the name of the second column

Comment: @John adding second column name worked for you?

Comment: @John you also need to name the table.